# Creating a "Save" Button for .txt files C#

Tags: c#, save

I have a form with some textboxes and comboboxes etc etc, with custom maid info from the user. so what i want to do, is to be abel to save the info in the boxes to a .txt file that you can read afterword like a normal .doc. But there is som problems that i don't know how to deal with. 
First off, the Path where the .txt file are going to be saved should be costumniceabel to user. with other worrds  the user should be abel to chose where to save the .txt file. When that is done i want to have it so that it write's everything down in that text doc. im pritty tierd now so i understand if you ppl cant read it, but please try and ask if u was unclear.

Comment: What you're asking is not so clear, so if the answer below doesn't fit your needs, let me know and I will adapt ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follows :

**Button callback :**

Create a Button and insert the below codes in its callback :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here comes the treatment
}
```

**Inner treatment :**

Build a parsable string (one line per property).

```
String str = "";
str += prop1 + "=" + this.textBox1.Text + "\n";
...
```

Use a `SaveFileDialog` for saving the file.

```
// Set the default file name
String path = getPreviousUserPath();    // A function to write by yourself
savefile.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
savefile.FileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
// Set filters - this can be done in properties as well
savefile.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*|"
// Display the save dialog
if(savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Save the properties to the file selected by the user
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(str);
    }
    setPreviousUserPath(savefile.FileName);    // A function to write by yourself
}
```

Note : After that you'll be able to load the file and parse it using '=' and '\n' separators to get back the previously saved properties.

Note : I'm just giving head lines here...

Comment: emm, i see now that i was pritty tierd yesterday... what i ment is that, i have some text in all kinds of textBoxes etc etc, then i have a save button, so that the user can save that info in a .txt file. but i have no idea of how to make that button first create that .txt file and if there already exists open it, then write down everything that are wiritten in the textBoxes etc etc. thats what i ment to say.
i tryed the code u gave me, i didnt work, got a lot of errors, functions missing etc etc.

Comment: `using System.IO; using System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog;` and `SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();` is theoretically all you need. Note : I'm trying to help here, but this is years I haven't used C# stuffs ;-). Also added braces that where missing...

Comment: If you want the program to remember where that user last saved the properties : just create a file `system_props.txt` where you keep the path of the last path he used. Then, while opening the `SaveFileDialog`, start by reading this system file to get the path and inject it to the `FileName` property of the dialog...